# getApplicationContext issue

Tags: android

I have VideoApplication class which extends Application class. I have created my other java class's object in this class so that I can pass it through activities.

```
public class VideoApplication extends Application {
      private Client client;
      public Client getClient(){
           return client;
      }
      public void setClient(Client client){
           this.client = client;
      }
}
```

I have added following line in androidManifest file:
`android.name=".VideoApplication"`.

But when I add the following line to my code(MainActivity.java), the application throws a ClassCastException exception.

```
VideoApplication appInstance = (VideoApplication)getApplicationContext();
```

Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: What Exception you are getting in Logcat?

Comment: Great code, but what seems to be the issue ? Cant solve it unless we know whats the issue. Please dont expect anyone to copy the code into a empty project to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure I am late to answer this but

```
android.name=".VideoApplication
```

doesn't seem right. I think it should be

```
android:name=".VideoApplication
```

I hope its not a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You might be causing a ClassCastException. Try using `getApplication()` not `getApplicationContext()`:

```
VideoApplication appInstance = (VideoApplication) getApplication();
```

Since you really want an Application object not a Context object.

Comment: Yes, I am getting classCastexception. So I even tried your solution but that also giving me same exception.

Comment: Please edit the LogCat errors into your question so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Suddenly it started working. I closed my eclipse and did clean again and then it started working with above code.
Thanks a lot to all. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using getClass().getName() on the instance to see actually which type is it and then do the proper cast.